# Apex Metadata API Layout Read-only fields being added as Read-write

Tags: apex, custom-field, metadata-api, page-layout, custom-metadata

We have Layout Read-only fields to be added. Seems like a bug, when we try to add read-only fields they become read-write on layout. Please see below example.

```
public class metadatatest {
    public static void runUpdateLayouts(){        
        Metadata.Layout la = getLayout('Account-Account Layout');

        Metadata.LayoutSection sec = new Metadata.LayoutSection();
        sec.customLabel = true;
        sec.detailHeading = true;
        sec.editHeading = true;
        sec.label = 'Custom fields';
        sec.style = metadata.LayoutSectionStyle.OneColumn;

        Metadata.LayoutColumn col1 = new Metadata.LayoutColumn();

        Metadata.LayoutItem layoutField = new Metadata.LayoutItem();

        layoutField.field = 'testfield__c';
        layoutField.behavior = metadata.UiBehavior.Readonly;

        col1.layoutItems.add(layoutField);
        sec.layoutColumns.add(col1);

        la.layoutSections.add(sec);

        Metadata.DeployContainer dc = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
        dc.addMetadata(la);

        Id jobid = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(dc,null);
    }

    public static Metadata.Layout getLayout(String layoutName){
        List<String> layoutList = new List<String>{layoutName};
            List<Metadata.Metadata> components = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, layoutList);
        return (Metadata.Layout)components[0];
    }
}
```

Above code will add testfield__c field to Account standard layout. But it shows as **Readonly in Layout editor**. But in Account both view and edit modes it's read-write.

Comment: The "Edit read-only fields" permission is set on the System Administrator profile. Have you tested under a different profile that does not have that permission set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Keith. This is a standard feature of a System Administrator profile. All Salesforce System Admins can edit read only fields. Also, standard Profiles are not editable at all.